# JAVA - Gui class won't open from another Gui Class

Tags: java, class, user-interface

Gui class closes the one I'm currently in but doesn't open my main menu gui class.

```
JButton btnNewButton_1 = new JButton("Main Menu");
        btnNewButton_1.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 13));
        btnNewButton_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                Main_GUI mainGUI = new Main_GUI();
                dispose();
            }
        });
```

main code that lists it set as visible, really not sure what is making it not work.main code that lists it set as visible, really not sure what is making it not work.

```
package GUI;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class Main_GUI extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Main_GUI frame = new Main_GUI();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
```

Comment: we need the code of that mainGUI, did you setVisible(true)?

Comment: Please give a [mcve]